# How can I add security tabs to Windows XP Home?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, permissions

I'm running Windows XP Home SP3.  My only partition is formatted with NTFS.
I need to be able to use the security tabs from XP Pro as shown in the picture but there are no options to enable them and I can't disable simple file sharing.

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you need to download and install the Security Configuration Manager from Microsoft.

The only known link to this file currently is on [Microsoft's FTP server](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/bussys/winnt/winnt-public/tools/SCM).

The file you want is SCESP4I.EXE.  Just download it and extract the files to a folder somewhere. Afterward, navigate to the folder the files were extracted to and run the  Setup.inf file by right clicking it and choosing `Install`.

When it's done, reboot the computer and you'll have your security tabs.

If you still don't have your tabs make sure you're logged in as an administrator.  Limited user accounts still aren't able to use this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use Safe Mode. It's a pain, but it does reveal the Security tab if you don't have Internet access